# ¿es correcta una navegacion usando php y ajax con html?

Tags: php, ajax

tengo la siguiente estructura de archivos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente intento realizar una navegacion simple entre paginas php, usando ajax: mi archivo index.php que carga el contenido que esta en documento1.php y  documento2.php, segun sea el caso cuando el usuario solicita la informacion:

```
<?php
 $section = isset($_GET['seccion']) ? $_GET['seccion']:'home';
?>
<form action="">
    <h1>homa soy la pagina de inicio, soy el header</h1>
    <h2>contenido que quieres ver:</h2>
        <input class="input__1"  type="button" value="informacion1">
        <input class="input__2"  type="button" value="informacion2">
        <div id="respuesta" class=""></div>
</form>
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
```

en mi archivo  script.js, envio la solicitud ajax a travez de get con n la variable apellido  que me dice que documento solicito el ususario una vez dio click en el input correspondiente:
const d = document;

```
//funcion que se ejecuta cuando el usuario da click en el boton de documento1 o documento2
function ejecutar(informacion){
    //solicitud a travez de ajax:
    const a = new XMLHttpRequest;
    //por get
    //envio la url y  la variable apellido guardo el contenido del value que corresponde a el input clickeado: 
    let url = "home.php?nombre=german&apellido=";
    url += informacion;
    a.open('GET', url, true);
    a.send(null);
    a.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(a.readyState == 4){
            if(a.status == 200){
                //en el div cargo la rspuesta procesada en el home.php, que es 
               document.getElementById('respuesta').innerHTML = a.responseText;
            }else if(a.status == 400){
                console.log("no encontrado")
            }
        }
    }
}
d.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
    console.log("di click en: ")
    if(e.target.matches(".input__1")){
       //cargue el documento1.php 
    }else if(e.target.matches(".input__2")){
        //cargue el documento2.php 
    }
    let informacion = e.target.value;
    ejecutar(informacion)
})
```

en mi archivo home porceso esa respuesta e incluyo el archivo documento1.php o documento2.php segun sea el caso,

```
<?php
//incluyo el doumento segun el valor enviado  atravez de la solicitud ajax:
if($_GET['apellido'] == 'informacion1'){
    include("informacion1.php");
}else if($_GET['apellido'] == 'informacion2'){
    include("informacion2.php");
}
?>
```

mis archivos documento1.php

```
<h2>documento 1</h2>
<p>contenido del documento # 1</p>
```

archivo documento2.php

```
<h2>documento 2</h2>
<p>contenido del documento # 2</p>
```

aqu esta el  resultado segun lo que el usuario solicita:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera si es correcto una navegacion de esta forma utilizando ajax, gracias, es par aun trabajo d ela u. : ).

Comment: buesca como usar los hash de javascript para navegar en lugar de usar redirecciones o link, con base n el hash puedes ir hacia adelante y hacia atras y no tendras que recargar la pagina, y tu codigo será ajax igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Correcto es, más o menos, pero no es del todo recomendable si son páginas distintas. ¿Qué pasa si quiero pasar a alguien un enlace directamente a "informacion2"? Porque la URL es la misma, por ejemplo, `https://localhost:8443/index.php` y no se altera según el documento.

Lo mismo para los motores de búsqueda, que cuando cargan una página comprueban su contenido directamente. Si tienen que pulsar un botón u otro y ejecutar JavaScript, no lo harán, y por tanto no podrán indexar tu página correctamente.

Por último, la experiencia de usuario. Si en vez de dos documentos hay 20 y quiero navegar al que estaba antes (en el navegador, sería la flecha hacia atrás); tal y como está implementado, no funcionará y me llevará a la página "real" anterior. En vez de estar en el doc 3 y volver al 2, me devolverá a la página en la que estaba antes (por ejemplo, Google).

Frameworks como Angular y React[1] que se usan muchas veces para Single-Page Applications (como la que estás intentando crear) solucionan estos problemas alterando manualmente el historial de la pestaña y la URL actual con [`window.history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), y haciendo que al cargar una página "de cero" cargue con la URL correcta.

Ahora bien, si bien se puede implementar todo esto de cero, hay un montón de cosas a tener en cuenta, y son bastante cosas a mantener; con lo que salvo que quieras dedicar horas a ello, no es recomendable, y es mejor cargar las páginas directamente desde el servidor (haciendo SSR, *Server-Side Rendering*) como se suele hacer con PHP.

[1]: Técnicamente React es una biblioteca, y el enrutamiento lo hace `react-router-dom`, pero para entendernos.

Comment: umn bueno gracias por la informacion, iguallo que intentaba es  implementar ajax para que las solicitudes no recarguen la pagina cada vez